# Unity Move() function doesn't work on Character controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What's wrong with the Move() function? When I use it on a character controller it highlights in red and creates an error log in the console.

Has this function been deprecated?

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMotor : MonoBehaviour {

    private CharacterController controller;

    void Start () {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update () {
        controller.Move(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? Also, Time.deltaTime will return you 0.000something. Very small. You're basically multiplying by nothing at that point so your movement speed would be minuscule.

Comment: Function Move() is just underlined like there is no such method at all

Comment: And what does the Unity error log say about it?

Comment: It says "Assets/Scripts/PlayerMotor.cs(16,20): error CS1061: Type `CharacterController' does not contain a definition for 'Move' and no extension method 'Move' of type 'CharacterController' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: What's your version of Unity? Did you check the scripting reference for your current version, and if so, does it exist?

Comment: My current version is 2017.3 and yes, the script reference exists

Comment: Quite the pickle, then. I can't see any reason it wouldn't be able to be seen.

Try checking in your editor for anything out of place. Ensure that your Player object has this script on it and also a character controller, just in case.
If that doesn't work, try re-importing the script.

Comment: Check that your project does not contain a CharacterController class you would have created.

Comment: Just to add on my previous comment, right click on the CharacterController type and select Go to Definition. This will tell you which class it is actually using.

Comment: @JamesWhyte multiplying velocities to move objects with `Time.DeltaTime` is common (and good) practice since it means the actual distance the object is moved per second no longer relies on the framerate.

Comment: @MargaritaBugaeva are there perhaps more classes named ` CharacterController`  in your solution? (and is the one you have referenced of the type `UnityEngine.CharacterController`)?

Comment: Try removing the "library" folder, and opening the project after that. It will import everything again.

Comment: @Everts thanks, that's it!